# How to override a HTML file using a custom module?

Tags: magento2, template, overrides, html

I'm developing a custom module for payment method in Magento 2. Currently, I'm using **cc-form.html** from vendor directory and module working fine. See below path:

> vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/web/template/payment/cc-form.html

Is there any way to override HTML file?

**Note:** I would like to override it using a custom extension. 
See below path:

> app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/web/template/payment/cc-form.html

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: when did you use this form, please show link or map site.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Working solution.

Just create or edit requirejs-config.js file from below path.

> /app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

And place below code in requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
          'Magento_Payment/template/payment/cc-form.html': 
              'Namespace_Module/template/payment/cc-form.html'
        }
  }
};
```

So we can override any html file in this way.

Comment: doesn't work for email template html file in module sales?

Comment: are we just creating registration.php,module.xml and composer.json then requirejs-config.js and the html?

Answer (score 19):

You can just add your cc-form.html file inside your theme payment module.

```
<mage_dir>/app/design/frontend/{Package}/{themename}/Magento_Payment/web/template/payment/cc-form.html
```

You can change according to your requirements at above place.

Remove **var** folder from root and remove **`pub/static/frontend`** folder.

You must have run command **`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`**

Clear your browser cache and check.

Comment: I know it will work fine if i place cc-form.html under my theme. but i am creating extension so i can't place it under theme. i must have to put this file under module's directory.

Comment: Thank you rakesh. i found the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37430036/override-html-file-in-custom-module-magento2/37464758#37464758

Answer (score 11):

Accepted solution is right, but I copy here [the full @AntonGuz answer from the "Stack Overflow"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37430036/override-html-file-in-custom-module-magento2/37464758#37464758) (very well explained):

> Yes, there is. You can look in pub static to see how path to static
>   asset constructed.
>
> ### How it works
>
> Every asset is accessible from the page by it`enter code here`s
>   "RequireJS ID". It similar to real path, but varied.
>
> For example file
>   `http://magento.vg/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico`.
>
> It's real path is
>   `/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/adminhtml/web/favicon.ico`.   It's
>   RequireJS ID is `Magento_Theme/favicon.ico`. This means that file
>   could be accessible via `require("text!Magento_Theme/favicon.ico")` or
>   similar command.
>
> You can find that *RequireJS ID* consist with module name and useful
>   part of path (after folder `web`).
>
> ### How can I replace a file
>
> So you have file
>   `vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/web/template/payment/cc-form.html`
>
> On the page it loaded with src as
>   `http://magento.vg/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Payment/template/payment/cc-form.html`
>
> So its RequireJS ID is
>   `Magento_Payment/template/payment/cc-form.html`
>
> Side note: Inside UI components stuff it equals to
>   `Magento_Payment/payment/cc-form`. Words "template" and ".html" are
>   added automatically.
>
> And now you can replace this file for application via RequireJS config
>
> ```
> var config = {
>   "map": {
>     "*": {
>       "Magento_Payment/template/payment/cc-form.html": 
>           "<OwnBrand>_<OwnModule>/template/payment/cc-form.html"
>     }
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> This code snippet you place in `requirejs-config.js` file in your
>   module. That is all.

Perhaps it will help somebody to understand as it occurs.

Comment: How do you add and modify the JS file for this html

Answer (score 7):

I don't know since which version of Magento2 it is required but if you want to override template from Magento_Ui module, you need to provide path like this:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            'ui/template/form/element/select.html':'Vendor_Module/templates/form/element/select.html'
        }
    }
};
```

Because in this file:

> vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/requirejs-config.js

There is path mapping:

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    paths: {
        'ui/template': 'Magento_Ui/templates'
    },
    map: {
        '*': {
            uiElement:      'Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/element/element',
            uiCollection:   'Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/collection',
            uiComponent:    'Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/collection',
            uiClass:        'Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/class',
            uiEvents:       'Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/events',
            uiRegistry:     'Magento_Ui/js/lib/registry/registry',
            consoleLogger:  'Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/console-logger',
            uiLayout:       'Magento_Ui/js/core/renderer/layout',
            buttonAdapter:  'Magento_Ui/js/form/button-adapter'
        }
    }
};
```