# How to override html file in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, checkout, overrides

I need to customize `Magento_Checkout` module.

I have tried to copied that `html` files into my theme path but the override is not working

Override path mentioned in below

```
/app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/web/template
```

But the file is taken from

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template
```

How to override this template `html` files?

Comment: Not working for me as well as trying to override `app\design\frontend\Magento\luma\Magento_Theme\templates\root.phtml` Home Page Why?

Comment: Deeban do you mean the Knockout html files? Or do you mean phtml files?

Comment: He is overriding Knockout HTML files & I'm trying phtml files

Comment: Cool, I've posted an answer for both html and phtml files.

Comment: your path is correct you need to remove cache of browser and remove pub/static folder from root and run command for deployment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll post the answer for both phtml and html files.

**Overriding phtml files**

For example if you want to override `site_name/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/shipping.phtml`, you will need to put it under `/site_name/app/design/frontend/ThemeName/default/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/shipping.phtml`

**Overriding (KO) html files**

For example if you want to override `/site_name/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.html`, you will need to put it under`/site_name/app/design/frontend/ThemeName/default/Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary/cart-items.html`

Now html pages can be a hassle, you need to make sure the caches from your browser are cleared. If you're using the latest google chrome you can inspect element go to network tab and then tick disable caches, reload the page. Reason for this is that HTML pages are more cacheable. If this does not work clear you `pub/static/frontend` folder.

Comment: Nope still not working. I have done above things & I also run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` & `clear cache` still not working.

Comment: Does anything else work under your theme?

Comment: Didn't check, but trying to override homepage it should work right?

Comment: It should work, maybe you missed something. Have you registered the theme?

Comment: I have below folder structure

`magento2
 |_ app
   |_ design
   |_ frontend
  |_ Magento
   |_luma
     |_Magento_Theme
       |_templates
      |_root.phtml
    composer.json
    registration.php
    theme.xml`

Comment: Would like to override Luma Theme

Comment: Does the theme.xml have the luma theme as the parent? Have you set your theme as the sites theme?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45955/discussion-between-ankit-shah-and-hm-hmm).

Comment: Hi phtml files are overriding perfectly

Comment: html files are not overriding

Comment: @Hmhmm Hi How to override html files

Comment: Did you follow clear browser caches, and pub/static/frontend folder?

Comment: @Hmhmm yes i cleared all caches

Comment: It should work,  what html file are you trying to change?

Comment: Google Chrome is a pain I went to settings clear my cache cleared magento cache still didn't see the overwrite but network tab tick disable caches worked for me!

Comment: This only works for phtml files, for the html  ones, and if the are loaded via KO, you can't do this

Comment: @Char why doesn't it work?

Comment: @Char have a look what the last comment from Juliano Vargas

Comment: This is what you have to do to override a HTML file https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/117236/55149

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the html file in Magento 2.1 then you need to follow few instructions :

1: Copy html file from /`Vendor/magento/module-catalog/web/template and paste in your theme (target directory) /app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/magento_catalog/web/template`

2: Delete the pub/static and var from root directory:

```
rm -rf pub/static/*
 rm -rf var/*
```

3: Deploy by SSH command:

```
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

4: Refresh the page.