# override knockout html template file in theme

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, html, knockoutjs, magento2.1.5

I need to add a class to the cart summary table caption.

I want to hide the caption by addding the class `sr-only` (bootstrap):

```
<caption class="table-caption sr-only" data-bind="text: $t('Total')"></caption>
```

The code is in the file `../Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/cart/totals.html`

I created my own base template and `<theme>` is a child of this (aka I don't extend from empty or luma). So I override the file in `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Checkout/web/template/cart/totals.html`

I deployed static content, flushed the cache (in the browser too).
So basically I did everything from this checked answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/138238/42007
But my added class does not appear.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was some caching bug. Cause after a night suddenly the correct template is loaded without any change.
I only wish I knew which caching caused the problem.
I did all the steps of `calypso`'s answer btw.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I need to do the same but damned if I can find where it's getting this from. I wish there was a cache:[clean|flush]-the-bloody-lot command!

Answer (score 5):

1. Check deploy mode, If deploy mode is not developer mode then set it.

   php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
2. Check **.htaccess** is in `pub/static/` folder or not. If not then please take from fresh magento and add it.
3. Delete this file `pub/static/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Checkout/web/template/cart/totals.html`
4. Deploy static content

rm -rf pub/static/*

rm -rf var/*

rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. I tried all of them but that didn't change the behavior. Although the file isn't at the path at 3.

Comment: But check my own answer. It was a caching problem. Only I don't know which cache. I even restarted the server and my computer without any luck. Today it just works...

Comment: Next time when you override .html file, If doesn't override then follow above steps. @4485670

Comment: yeah as I said I did, but it didn't work either. there must be some additional cache interfering.

Comment: To note: if in developer mode you shouldn't be deploying static-content at all. pub/static/frontend should be empty. Then it should be fetching everything on-the-fly. If you deploy any static content, then you'll have to manage that constantly as it will always use what's in pub/static in preference to your changes. Deploying static content should be reserved for Production mode only, as the notification will tell you!

Comment: You don't have to deploy static content in developer mode ...

Answer (score 0):

You can also just go to

```
/pub/static
```

folder from your Magento root and then browse the path of any file that you wish to locate. In this case

```
pub/static/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/en_US/Magento_Checkout/template/cart
```

and then manually delete totals.html

After that go back to your browser and just refresh the page. The newest version of the deleted file will refresh into the static cache and you'll see all your latest changes.

This way there is no need to run

```
php bin/magento cache:flush 
rm -rf var/generation/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/frontend/*
```

Neither there is need to clear your browser caches.

This works great for both localhost and on server, in developer mode. In production mode, you'll need to selectively redeploy static resources.