# How to override Magento checkout shipping.html

Tags: magento2, checkout, theme

```
myproject/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html
```

Overring using the fallback.

```
myproject/app/design/frontend/Solace/olsto_child/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html
```

I tried to modify the file : **shipping.html** , but it didn't get overriden
any solution let me know if I am doing the right way or wrong.

Comment: Why is there  "web/web" ?Remove one "web" and try. Clear your cache as well.

Comment: @GeethikaAntony its single web  myproject/app/design/frontend/Solace/olsto_child/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html

Comment: Should work without issue, just clear cache. What does `deploy:mode:show` return? If your mode is Production you have to recompile your theme

Answer (score 1):

Use `requirejs-config.js`. Location of this should be `app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

`var config = {
    paths: {
        'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping': '[VendorName]_[ModuleName]/template/shipping'
    }
};`

Also clear your static folder files and run `php bin/magento static-content:deploy`

If you want to override this in your theme follow steps in this [How to override html file in magento 2.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138223/how-to-override-html-file-in-magento-2-1)

Comment: var config = {
    paths: {
        'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping': 'Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping',

getting 404 error

Comment: No, you have to replace [VendorName] and [ModuleName] with your vendor and module correspondingly.

Comment: I did try Smartware_Magento_Checkout/template/shipping

Comment: Hi @Sam 'Smartwave' is your module name right? What about the vendor name? We don't need the Magento_checkout part. It should be Smartwave_modulename/template/shipping

Comment: @Sam I have updated my answer please check that also.

Answer (score 1):

correct path to override would be the following:

```
(magento_dir)/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html
```

delete things under:

```
/var/viewprocessed/
/pub/static/frontend/
```

I am assuming you are on linx here.
go to the console and navigate to `(magento_dir)/bin/`

from within the bin folder, issue the commands in the following order:

```
./magento setup:static-content:deploy
./magento cache:flush
```

it takes some time to deploy the static content. so wait before you flush the cache.

Clean the cache in your web browser and try to view your page that you want to override.

Hope this is clear enough and works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
myproject/app/design/frontend/Solace/olsto_child/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html
```

instead of

```
myproject/app/design/frontend/Solace/olsto_child/Magento_Checkout/web/web/template/shipping.html
```

Also if changes are not affecting, then remove var, generation and pub/static folder and then deploy content again.

Comment: please check I have corrected the path
-> cleared cache

myproject/app/design/frontend/Solace/olsto_child/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html

Comment: Ok.  If changes are not affecting, then remove var, generation and pub/static folder and then deploy content again.

Comment: I did try but its not overriding the changes

Comment: do you have final solution? I got the same situation

Comment: Any solution?????

Answer (score 0):

create: app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
          'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping.html': 'VendorName_ModuleName/template/shipping.html'          
        }
    }
};
```

or

Move: file to this path, then **compile**.

```
myproject/app/design/frontend/Solace/olsto_child/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html
```