# How to overide checkout-agreements.html template

Tags: magento2, checkout

I was trying to overide checkout-agreements.html template via app/code and i created

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
          'Magento_CheckoutAgreements/template/checkout/checkout-agreements.html': 
          'Nami_CheckoutAgreements/template/checkout/checkout-agreements.html'
        }
    }
  };
```

Next i created

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/checkout-agreements.html

It's almost working becasue template is override but console show this error
[image]

And when i try place order, console showing me this error and order is not completed.

[image]

Any ideas? I was trying overdie this checkout-agreements.html via app/design/frontend/Vendor/MyTheme/Magento_CheckoutAgreements/web/template/checkout/checkout-agreements.html

But it's not working and now i dont have any ideas. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think requirejs is where you overwrite template html file.

There an answer already on stackexchange, you can check it here [How to override html file in magento 2.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138223/how-to-override-html-file-in-magento-2-1/138238#138238)

Another way to do this is you can write your own JS-module which extends from original module - the module that render/use that html template file.

From your own module, use your own template. Then use requirejs config to change the core module to your module.

Comment: When I overide template via ```app/design/frontend/Vendor/MyTheme/Magento_CheckoutAgreements/web/template/checkout/checkout-agreements.html ```
it's working but console returns error with duplicate input, and place order not completed. 

How should I create reqiresjs-config-js to solve this problem? Where should i place reqiresjs-config-js file? Please help

Comment: didn't you read the link I sent?

Comment: Yes and override is working but i can't place order on my checkout page because console returns error like above

Comment: but the link doesn't mention `require` or `js` anywhere? so I don't understand what are you trying to say here?

Comment: Yes, and i override template via ```app/design/frontend/Vendor/MyTheme/Magento_CheckoutAgreements/web/template/checkout/checkout-agreements.html ```
I created only this path, and it's workin but error with duplicates still remains.

I delete my custom module and I do not use the requiresjq-config anywhere

Comment: I solved this problem. It's my bad i created bad tamplete file. Thanks for your time and thank for help.

Comment: Great! Happy to help!