# How to overwrite the files in the "template" folder that contains the html files

Tags: template

How to overwrite a file in the "template" folder that contains html files? I'm not talking about the "templates" folder that contains the phtml files. I tried overwriting the same way but it seems like some elements stopped working correctly.

Comment: Please check the attached link as it already solved and it's working one. 

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116857/how-to-override-a-html-file-using-a-custom-module

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override a HTML file using a custom module?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116857/how-to-override-a-html-file-using-a-custom-module)