# Mini Cart is not loading perfectly after upgrading magento 2.3.5 to 2.4.3

Tags: magento2

[image]

After upgrading magento 2.3.5 to 2.4.3 minicart content is not loading perfectly."view and edit cart" and "Go to checkout" content is not rendering. Is there anyone who can guide me to accomplish that?

Comment: Please disable the third-party modules, related to cart/checkout customization. And check.

Comment: is working with the default theme?. can you please check with the default theme. maybe override the mini cart file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too faced this issue in one of my projects. The issue was in one of the third-party modules, they used a code to close the mini cart using a close sidebar but when I checked I didn't find the close sidebar observable in any of the files.

1. The issue in my scenario was due to the below-shown code and you can see **closesidebar()** in that [image]
2. The fix is applied by replacing the above section with core code. The core file is **Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/content.html** and you can replace using requirejs-config.js map (Reference: [Map the HTML file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116857/how-to-override-a-html-file-using-a-custom-module)). [image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file thats cause the error is coming from a none Core module because the path is "static/frontend/Pea..." you will need to check if this is a thirdparty module and update it.

Comment: "static/frontend/Pea..." is a theme path. this is not a third-party module.

Comment: you're correct!