# How to overide a html template

Tags: magento2, template, overrides, tax, template-override

I want to override

`vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/shipping_method/price.html`

So I have copied the file to my custom theme to:

`app/design/frontend/Company/Theme/Magento_Tax/web/template/checkout/shipping_method/price.html`

But it's not overriding. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think from JS from which it is calling but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Override both `JS` and `HTML` file

`vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/shipping_method/price.html`

`vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/shipping_method/price.js`

Override in Your theme

`app/design/frontend/Company/Theme/Magento_Tax/web/template/checkout/shipping_method/price.html`

`app/design/frontend/Company/Theme/Magento_Tax/web/js/view/checkout/shipping_method/price.js`

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

**Cheers !! You overrided in perfect way**

look like still it's serving from cache

run below command

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

if production mode then run below command too

`php bin/magento s:s:d`

and in last run

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

in browser go to network tab and search for **price.html** open in in new tab or check here response your code reflected or not.

**Note: if any 3rd party cache(Varnish,Cloudfare,Radis,FPC) or Cpanel Cache enable then clear it.**

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is likely storing the HTML file in it's cache, flush browser cache and try again.

Answer (score 0):

var config = {
map: {
'*': {
'Magento_Tax/template/checkout/shipping_method/price.html':
'Namespace_Module/template/checkout/shipping_method/price.html'
}
}
};

Comment: better understanding you can take reference from this url 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116857/how-to-override-a-html-file-using-a-custom-module